# Install wine on unconnected computer

Tags: installation, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I run ubuntu 10.10 currently on my desktop which is not connected to the wifi so I want to know if it possible to download wine in one package using my windows laptop to install on the desktop computer without running into dependency problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

Launch Synaptic on your Ubuntu. Mark for install Wine, then go to File -> Generate package download list. Save it and copy to desktop computer. Then just download all files from script and install them to Ubuntu.